# Conditonal Modal in JS

Tags: javascript

I need help creating a conditonal pop up modal when no results are found from an API call.

When the API returns a result: length:0 from the array I would like a modal to appear that says no results found.

The CSS is working. This is my HTML + JS

HTML

```
        <div class="modal" id="myModal">
          <div class="modal-content">
          <span class="close">&times;</span>
          <p>Sorry no results found</p>
        </div>
        </div>
        <button class="btn" id="searchBtn">Search</button>
```

JS

```
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
var btn = document.getElementById("searchBtn");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

btn.onclick = function(){
// for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
// if (data[i].length === 0) {
modal.style.display = "block";
};

span.onclick = function(){
modal.style.display = "none";
};

window.onclick = function(event) {
if (event.target == modal) {
modal.style.display = "none";
};
```

API call code

```
   var newRecipe = 
   'https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/findByIngredients?ingredients='+ 
   allIngreds + '&number=10&apiKey=39791063581a4d96a908bb19745b3f64';

   fetch(newRecipe)
  .then(response => {
     if (!response.ok){
        throw Error("ERROR")
     };
     return response.json();
    })
   .then(data => {
   console.log(data);
   });
```

Comment: so did you add `modal.style.display = "block";` at your promise's `then` function? (when of course the result is the expected?)

Comment: i have not, how would i input this into my code?

Comment: please add your api call code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the api call that you posted, it should be sth like this

```
   fetch(newRecipe)
  .then(response => {
     if (!response.ok){
        throw Error("ERROR")
     };
     return response.json();
    })
   .then(data => {
   console.log(data);
   if (data.length === 0) {
     modal.style.display = "block";
   } else {
     modal.style.display = "none";
   }
   });
```